# github protected branch - require pull request

Tags: git, github

In my GitHub repo, I would like to prevent all but a few privileged accounts from pushing directly to my `master` branch. From what I've seen, I can use protected branches for this.

The thing is, I do want members of my team to be able to create their own branches and  submit pull requests into master from them. In fact, I even want these team members to be able to approve their own pull requests. Perhaps we will institute a review feature someday, but right now we're too small and don't have the bandwidth for it.

But I'd still prefer not to have them push *directly* to master. The idea being that at least by having to go through a pull request, there are certain mental checks a person will have to do before merging it.

Can this be done with protected branches, or is this just a "soft" policy thing?

Comment: What is wrong with the soft policy approach?

Comment: Nothing, but it would be nice to prevent people pushing things accidentally, if nothing else.

Comment: Isn't protecting `master` exactly what you describe that you want?

Comment: I tried specifically restricting pushes to master, but then people were not able to merge their own pull requests. I still want them to be able to merge into master using the pull request system, just not directly using their own client. Seems that's not how the system is designed to work, though...