# Single User GitHub Repository - How to protect master, but allow my own PR's?

Tags: github

Research I've done before raising this question:

- `[github] single user pr` - no relevant results
- `[github] single user pull request` - no relevant results
- `[github] approve own pull request`

  - [github protected branch require pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984297/github-protected-branch-require-pull-request?s=1%7C92.3916) (Unanswered)
  - A potentially relevant question, but around a multiple user environment, so there were workarounds.  I don't have a workaround.
- '[github] approve own pr` - no relevant results.
- Quite a few Google searches

---

So my problem is simple: I have a personal GitHub repository that I am using to manage my website code.  I would like to prevent accidental check-ins to the `master` branch because I do not want the CI/CD pipeline that I'm building to trigger unless a feature is complete; I'm planning to use issue-linked feature branches to handle updates.

My problem is that I cannot seem to set this up without having someone else to approve the pull requests, which I don't have.  So the question is: How, other than creating a secondary git account to handle PR's, can I protect a branch to prevent accidental check-ins from happening, without having someone else on my team to approve those pull requests?

I know that I can do this in Azure Repositories, however, I quite like the GitHub environment so I'd rather do this in GitHub.

Comment: One option I can think of is to change your default branch to "dev" or something so that all pushes happen to dev unless you explicitly checkout master branch in client. Another option is "git hooks". I've not tried it myself, but they may fit your use case (Client side pre-push or server side pre-receive).

Comment: it was something similar to that which I ended up doing - see the answer I posted for details.  I think this is just a limitation of the GitHub front-end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around this.  At the time I made this request, I didn't have automated tests set up (Something I believe all projects should have for completeness).  When I set up validation requirements to merge into Master, I could not directly check-in to Master because those checks had not been run.

I could still approve the PR myself, so that was allowable, however, I also had to ensure that all pipeline checks had completed before that PR could complete.

It's not a complete answer because if you are not running a CI/CD pipeline with test running you will not be able to take advantage - but it's easy enough to set something dummy up that will always pass to enable this solution.  Until GitHub.com provides a self-approval allowance, it seems to be the best answer.

I'm always happy to hear alternatives though!